# Using a foreign key in Oracle SQL to display text data

Tags: sql, oracle10g, foreign-keys

New to Oracle SQL and I assume that this is a very straight forward question but I can't find a direct answer. I have an employees table in my database. One of the columns is 'emp_state' which is to show the State in which the employee resides. I also have a 'Customer' table and an 'office' table, which also both have a 'State' field. To reduce the amount of redundant data in my database, I have created a 'State' table, which will have all the states with a corresponding ID. I want to reference this table in the other tables as mentioned. When setting up my table, what should I define as the foreign key in the relevant tables? Should it be 'State_id' or 'State_name'? I want the state name to appear in any queries that are run, rather than the state ID which would be meaningless to a user.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should use state_id. If is much faster to `join` on a `INT` then a `VARCHAR`.
- If you need the name if a state the you should `JOIN` on the table and get it
- If you are planing to update the state name then you need to update all the relate tables. If you have a id then you just need to update the name column.
- You would probably not have the same state name twice. But what if you do? Then you must change it or append some strange number on the state name.

So bottom line: Always use the id

Comment: replace the existing state columns with a new state_id.  This might take a few iterations depending on how 'dirty' your original data is.

Comment: True. But the benefits on having a int id instead of a varchar forenkey is worth the inconvenient

Comment: oh - i totally agree... (hence upvote) i'm just extending the idea that you will be building a new (int) column to replace the old (varchar) col - then updating the ID values before whacking the original...

Comment: It was the JOIN that I was looking for. That's the link that I was missing. So I specify the 'emp_state' as a NUMBER column and set it as a foreign key related to 'state_id' on the 'state' table. Thanks for that Arion EDIT: I don't have to alter any old columns I'm in the very early stages of the design. Wanted to get it right from the start!